# Diameter of finite and bounded martingales

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, martingales

I am interested in the solution of the following problem: for a fixed $n$, find

$$\sup\ \ \mathbb{E}\max_{1\le i<j\le n}|M_i-M_j|^p,$$
where supremum is taken over all the martingales
$$M_1, \ M_2, \ \dots, \ M_n,$$
such that $ \ 0  \le  M_n\le 1 \ $ a.e. I am mostly concerned with the case of $ \ p \ $ equal to $ \ 1 \ $ or $ \ 2$.

This problem looks as if it must have been solved a long time ago. Have You ever encountered it? I know that there are similar articles for continues time case (with cadlag assumptions) but I would like to find a discrete version as stated above.

I would be very grateful if someone would point me towards an appropriate book or paper.

Comment: John, are you looking for an exact computation of the supremum or by an upper bound?

Comment: I would be extremely happy to find that someone have already computed the exact supremum in book/paper. But seeing how to compute an upper bound would also be very interesting and informative.